# APK upload certificate error on Google Play Console

Tags: android, android-install-apk, google-console-developer

I have just finished some very minor bug fixes on our app and have generated a signed APK. I have tried to upload this on Google Play Console to give a release but I get this error. I have used the correct Keystore and application runs fine when tested on a device.

ere is the error:

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 7D:24:1D:9B:55:33:AC:7D:C6:72:E6:4B:45:83:92:B1:BF:60:3C:D6 ]
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: CB:8F:D6:DD:68:DA:40:3B:D9:46:6D:F4:5C:C1:A5:EB:3B:17:04:93 ]

Any ideas why?

Thank you.

Comment: Do as the error message says. Check if the keystore file(to sign the app) of new and old app is the same. Check the build(debug/release). Find it. You must be missing something.

Comment: Keystore is exactly the same. Also it's a release version.

Comment: And Android studio version?

Comment: Android Studio version is 2.3.3

Comment: Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you are using the same keystore then it should be working fine.

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't work.